# **failed": true} msg: Failed to lock apt for exclusive operationFATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting**

Tags: ssh, sudo, ansible

I get the error

> {"**failed": true} msg: Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation
>
> FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting**

But I can successfully ssh into the remote host

This is the content of my playbook

```
- hosts: 172.30.0.12
  roles:
  - java
  - tomcat
    sudo: True
  vars:
    tomcat_version: 7
    java_version: 7
    tomcat_jmxremote_enable: true
    tomcat_jmxremote_port: 10003
```

Kindly help me figure this out

Comment: ansible is successfully ssh'ing into the server too. What is the actual task that is failing? What does its task definition look like?

Comment: As @tedder42 stated - please update your playbook to include the task that is failing.  It would also be helpful to run the playbook with -vvvv and provide all the output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `root` to lock apt or use apt-commands in your system, so just add :

```
sudo: yes
```

to your **task** *(and I guess `sudo: True` on the role does not work)*  and it will work.

Comment: `sudo: yes` is old fashion and will be deprecate in next versions. Instead, use become/become_user as said in `chishaku`'s answer.

Answer (score 2):

As tchap said, "You need to use root to lock apt or use apt-commands in your system."

However, from ansible 1.9, `sudo` has been deprecated.  You now need to add the `become` and `become_user` directives to your playbook.

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  become: true
  become_user: root
```